# Maven commands cannot be executed in IntelliJ terminal anymore. What could be the reason for that?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, terminal

I use IntelliJ and its bundled maven. On Friday i successfully executed commands like

```
mvn -U clean compile
```

But yesterday, when i tried to execute them, message

```
command not found : mvn
```

appears.
The only reason that i could think about, is that i am working in the wrong shell (all this appears in Mac) but i believe i executed the stuff in the right shell (zsh).

On the right, where there is maven tab, the commands from the lifecycle like Clean and Compile are successfully executed.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you execute maven commands in OS terminal? Check the shell, specified in Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Tools | Terminal | **Shell path** and compare it to the system OS shell. You need to make sure the `mvn` command executable is added to this shell's `PATH` environment variable.